# SQL-запрос на обновление данных

Tags: java, sql, oracle

В таблице четыре колонки `id`, `name`, `description` и `price`. Мне надо создать метод void changeDescription() который удаляет последнее предложение из description всех продуктов с длинной описания более 100. Метод я сделал до момента удаления последнего предложения.

```
private static void changeDescription(){
        try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS); Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {

            String descriptionNew = "";
            try(ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT")){
                while (resultSet.next()){
                    String description = resultSet.getString(3);
                    if (description.length() > 100){
                        String[] arraySentences = description.split("[.]");
                        arraySentences[arraySentences.length - 1] = "";
                        for (String sentence : arraySentences){
                            if (sentence != null && !sentence.isEmpty()){
                                descriptionNew += sentence + ".";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(descriptionNew);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.err.println("Something went wrong");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

А вот дальше не знаю как сделать, чтобы обновились данные в таблице, в колонке Description. Как в запрос на обновление подставить `descriptionNew`?

Comment: А просто `UPDATE` написать нельзя?

Comment: Dmitry, подскажите как, если надо убрать последнее предложение только в тех описаниях, где длина описания более 100 символов ? Я не знаю как это указать в простом запросе UPDATE. Тип Description в таблице указан CLOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще сделать все в одном `UPDATE` довольно просто. Общая идея такая:

```
update product
   set description = case when instr(description, '.', -1, 2) = 0 then description 
                          else substr(description, 1, instr(description, '.', -1, 2)) end
 where length(description) > 100;
```

Выражение `instr(description, '.', -1, 2)` ищет вторую точку с конца. Если не находит (возвращает `0`), то описание не изменяется, если находит - то далее берется подстрока с первого символа до этой точки. Тут, конечно, много допущений: что нет многоточий, сокращений, нет дат и чисел с точками-разделителями, точки стоят в конце каждого предложения и т. д. Но в общем виде задача поиска последнего предложения все равно не решаемая. Разве что нейросетями.

Вторая проблема с типом `CLOB`. Запрос выше хорошо будет работать только с `varchar2`, а с `CLOB` лучше использовать пакет `DBMS_LOB`. В нем есть точно такие же функции `substr` и `instr`.

Comment: Dmitry, спасибо за Ваш ответ. Я пытаюсь решить эту задачу более простым, как мне кажется, для меня путем. На уровне тех знаний, которые получаю в процессе обучения. С такими сложными запросами, как Вы показали, я ещё не умею работать. Но всё равно, спасибо за помощь )))

Comment: Вообще, если задача учебная и ее цель не состоит в том, чтобы научиться работать с `CLOB`, лучше брать `varchar2`. И если ограничение в 4000 символов устраивает.

Comment: И чего в запросе сложного? Там даже джойнов нет :)))

Comment: Задача учебная и условия задачи, к сожалению, задаю не я. )))

Comment: Мы ещё не проходили такие ключевые слова как case when, then, метод instr(), substr(). Поэтому пытаюсь решить на том уровне инструментов, которые мне уже известны. А может и не в правильном направлении двигаюсь при решении этой задачи. Поэтому тут вопрос и задал такой.

Comment: Так я потому и спросил про `UPDATE`. Допускает ли учебное задание решение на SQL, или это задача для решения на java. Что касается "не проходили", имхо, глупо ждать разрешения от преподавателя на использование функции. А если вы ее вообще не пройдете?

Comment: Согласен, что ждать глупо. Но надо решать теми инструментами, которые прошли. Получается тут надо совместить и java и SQL ))) Одним запросом SQL я достаю то, что находится в колонке description с условием по длине, посредством java убираю последнее предложение и следующим запросом SQL обновляю данные в этом description. Почти решил уже, осталась проблема только в том, что во все строки записывается один результат, а должен свой для каждой строки. Надеюсь объяснил не коряво ))